# Counting duplicate entries and sorting them based on category

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, match

Just need some help on how to go about using a SQL statement that checks for duplicate entries in a column called interest_desc and then sorts them by what categoryID they are assigned to.

The perfect outcome would be and echo like;

"Fishing" is the most popular interest in the category "4"

Struggling to know where to begin :S

Update - I have this now thanks to your help however i believe my syntax is wrong?

```
$interestCatPopular = "SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat    FROM
(
SELECT 
interest_desc,
categoryID,
COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
FROM tbl
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
) subsel 
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID";

$mostPopularInterest = mysql_query($interestCatPopular) or die(mysql_error());

$arrayResults = mysql_fetch_assoc($mostPopularInterest);
foreach ($arrayResults as $result) {
echo "{$result['interest_desc']} was the most popular in category   {$result['categoryID']} with {$result['num_in_cat']} occurrences\n";
}
```

:)

Comment: Does interest_desc contain single words, a list of words (e.g. comma-separated), or a full text description?

Comment: Oh, then my answer might be over-complicated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery, you can first count the number in each category. From that, the outer query selects the maximum count along with the corresponding `categoryID` and `interest_desc`.

This query should result in the most popular `interest_desc` for each `categoryID`, plus how many occurrences it had. Of course, it's untested.

```
SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat FROM
(
SELECT 
  interest_desc,
  categoryID,
  COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
FROM tbl
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
) subsel 
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
```

In PHP, following a successful query and looping call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` into an array `$results`:

#### Update

You need to fetch your results in a loop:

```
// Load $arrayResults in a loop...
$arrayResults = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mostPopularInterest)) {
  $arrayResults[] = $row;
}

foreach ($arrayResults as $result) {
  echo "{$result['interest_desc']} was the most popular in category   {$result['categoryID']} with {$result['num_in_cat']} occurrences\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, ive updated mine with an example of your code however i think the syntax is wrong? :S

Comment: @JBUCL You didn't have a loop to load $arrayResults. See above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM 
(
   SELECT category, interest_desc, COUNT(*) as num
   FROM category_table
   GROUP BY category,interest_desc
)a
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT category, MAX(num) AS max_num 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT category, interest_desc, COUNT(*) as num
   FROM category_table
   GROUP BY category,interest_desc
 )b
 GROUP BY b.category
)c ON c.category = a.category AND a.num = c.max_num
```